# Find the Z coordinate of point within plane

Tags: three.js, computational-geometry, turfjs

From the 3 black points I found the plane

```js
const { Vector3, Plane } = require('three')

const points = [new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 0, 1), new Vector3(1, 2, 0)]
const plane = new Plane().setFromCoplanarPoints(...points)
```

[image]

But how do I get the Z coordinate of the fourth red point (example: `(0.75, 0.75, z)`) that lies in the plane?

This doesn't seem to work:

```js
const targetPoint = new Vector3()
plane.projectPoint(new Vector3(0.75, 0.75, 0), targetPoint)

/*
Vector3 {
  x: 0.5833333333333334,
  y: 0.8333333333333334,
  z: 0.16666666666666666
}
*/
```

An answer with TurfJS would be also perfectly OK

Comment: How could TurfJS guess that you want a vertical projection rather than an orthogonal one ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust `turf.planepoint`

Answer (score 0):

Just for others to know, I solved with TurfJS using its method [`planepoint`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/planepoint).

The method `polygon` has as 1st parameter an array of Linear Rings, and a Linear Ring must have the same first and last points, thus a triangle has 4 points. `a, b, c` represent the ordered heights.

```js
const turf = require('@turf/turf')

const point = turf.point([0.75, 0.75])
const triangle = turf.polygon([[
  [0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 2], [0, 0]
]], {
  a: 0,
  b: 1,
  c: 0
})
const zValue = turf.planepoint(point, triangle) // 0.375
```